# Modify a token from pathauto module

Tags: path-aliases, tokens

pathauto provides a hook called:[node:menu-link:parents:join-path]

```
    /**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 */
function pathauto_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
  $replacements = array();

  if ($type == 'array' && !empty($data['array'])) {
    $array = $data['array'];
foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
  switch ($name) {
    case 'join-path':
      module_load_include('inc', 'pathauto');
      $values = array();
      foreach (element_children($array) as $key) {
        $value = is_array($array[$key]) ? render($array[$key]) : (string) $array[$key];
        $value = pathauto_cleanstring($value);
        $values[] = $value;
      }
      $replacements[$original] = implode('/', $values);
      break;
  }
}
  }

  return $replacements;
}
```

How can I implement a modification of this hook for my site? I would like to limit the depth of the parent trail to 2 levels. I think I could achieve this by modifying this line like this:

```
   $replacements[$original] = implode('/', array_slice($values, 0, 2));
```